# Help restoring a mongodump 3.4 backup into a different instance

Tags: mongodb

I am working on backup recovery for `MongoDB 3.4`. We have an instance that is running and being used. I set up a instance for doing testing of the backup and recovery process. In order to get data I did `mongodump` for each database and copied the files to my test server. Each backup write files to a directory that has the same name as the database. I used the gzip option to make it easier to move the files around. I am having issues trying to do the `mongorestore`. Can someone give me the syntax for `mongorestore`?

Here is the dump command

```
mongodump --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u my_admin_user
          -p password -o /backup_dir --gzip -d test_db
```

(split to multiple lines for readability)

These are the directories with the contents of my_test_db

```
root@my_vm:~/mongodb_backup_full_data_dump > ls -l
total 20
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 13:30 admin
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 13:51 data1
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 14:20 data2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 14:20 data3
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 14:20 my_test_db
root@my_vm:~/mongodb_backup_full_data_dump > ls -l ./my_test_db/*
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    24263 Aug 24 14:20 ./my_test_db/journal_entries.bson.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      132 Aug 24 14:20 ./my_test_db/journal_entries.metadata.json.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      481 Aug 24 14:20 ./my_test_db/journal_users.bson.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      107 Aug 24 14:20 ./my_test_db/journal_users.metadata.json.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 14438174 Aug 24 14:20 ./my_test_db/test_collection.bson.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root      104 Aug 24 14:20 ./my_test_db/test_collection.metadata.json.gz
```

and, this is what happens when I try to do the restore:

```
mongorestore --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u my_admin_user -p password -o /backup_dir \
--gzip -d test_db /root/mongodb_backup_full_data_dump/test_db/journal_entries.bson.gz



2017-08-25T15:24:05.487-0400    the --db and --collection args should only be used when restoring from a BSON file. Other uses are deprecated and will not exist in the future; use --nsInclude instead
2017-08-25T15:24:05.487-0400    checking for collection data in /root/mongodb_backup_full_data_dump/mediax
2017-08-25T15:24:05.487-0400    Failed: error scanning filesystem: file /root/mongodb_backup_full_data_dump/mediax is a directory, not a bson file
```

Comment: Can you post what you tried and what error are you getting. There are examples here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#examples

Comment: I was able to get a restore command working by specifying each bson file.  One of the directories has a few dozen bson files and I am currently running the import for those. I am getting duplicate key error collection messages. I'm not sure why. I was hoping that I could run one command and get every file in the directory at once. I am still not sure that I am doing the right thing.

Comment: `mongorestore --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password "pass" /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24`  with `--gzip` should work. Did you try with '--collection` switch at least for the collection where you have many files?

Comment: I tried using the directory only, the error is above.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is

```
mongorestore --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase admin -u my_admin_user -p password --gzip /root/mongodb_backup_full_data_dump/
```

So, you just tell the directory (basedir) where "all" backups are. mongorestore will "restore" those files (in those sub-directories) to databases (come from directory name).

SO, if you change that "test_db" directory name (`mv test_db other_test_db`) to "other_test_db", it will restore those files to "other_test_db"

Answer (score 0):

Start a mongod instance for a new single-node replica set. Specify the path to the backup data files with --dbpath option and the replica set name with the --replSet option. For config server replica set (CSRS), include the --configsvr option.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --replSet <replName>
```

Connect a mongo shell to the mongod instance

```
mongo
```

Initiate the new replica set.

```
rs.initiate()
```

MongoDB initiates a set that consists of the current member and that uses the default replica set configuration.

For detailed information Please [Click Here](http://www.mongoing.com/docs/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup.html)